# how to send values to input with readonly

Tags: python

```
<input type="text" name="pf_filename_0" size="57" maxlength="255" value="" class="d-pr-calc-files-maint85073" tabindex="3" style="position:absolute; left:0.875in; top:0.427in; width:3.792in;" readonly="" onfocus="{d_pr_calc_files_maint.itemGainFocus(0,6,this,d_pr_calc_files_maint.gobs.pf_filename); d_pr_calc_files_maint.selectControlContent(this);}" onclick="{var ret;  ret= d_pr_calc_files_maint.itemClicked(0,6,'pf_filename',0); return ret;}" onchange="{this.bChanged = true;}" onkeypress="return DW_EditKeyPressed(event, this, -1);" onblur="{d_pr_calc_files_maint.itemLoseFocus (this);}">

<input type="text" name="pf_filename_0" size="57" maxlength="255" value="" class="d-pr-calc-files-maint85073" tabindex="3" style="position:absolute; left:0.875in; top:0.427in; width:3.792in;" readonly="" onfocus="{d_pr_calc_files_maint.itemGainFocus(0,6,this,d_pr_calc_files_maint.gobs.pf_filename); d_pr_calc_files_maint.selectControlContent(this);}" onclick="{var ret;  ret= d_pr_calc_files_maint.itemClicked(0,6,'pf_filename',0); return ret;}" onchange="{this.bChanged = true;}" onkeypress="return DW_EditKeyPressed(event, this, -1);" onblur="{d_pr_calc_files_maint.itemLoseFocus (this);}"
```

Comment: <div name="file_frame" id="file_frame" style="display: block;"><input type="file" name="fo_file" id="fo_file" style="POSITION:absolute;left:8;top:10;width:430;z-index = 9;" onchange="fnEnable()"></div>

Answer (score 0):

please provide more information and elaborate more on your question.

But from what i understood from your post, you are declaring some readonly inputs and then trying to send some data to them.

ReadOnly inputs are meant to be given their values on declaration/creation.